# Closing a menu when a click is not on the menu by removing a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have seen quite a bit on this topic of closing a menu when a click is not on the menu, but the question I have is, can you simply right the below code to be - if you do not click on #menu > ul > li > a removeClass open.  Something like onclick !== css...?

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').on('click', function(){
        $("#cssmenu ul").removeClass("open");
    });
```

Comment: From a UX point of view, I would also close the menu when you unhover it. Now you are asking people to click on a webpage, which might scare them, because who know what can happen when you click anywhere on a page.

Comment: @VaMoose I have not tried anything as I am not sure how to write the statement if a user does not click on this > remove class.  I just need to have the above jQuery code rewritten with the if not clicked on.

Comment: Good point on the hover.  This portion of the code won't be used on desktop - just mobile though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="cssmenu" class="open">
        Content goes here
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}

#cssmenu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
}

.open {
    background: green !important;
}
```

And finally JS:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
var element = $("#cssmenu");

if (element.has(e.target).length === 0 && !element.is(e.target)) {
    // click outside of the element
    element.removeClass("open");
}
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wtaoxma/1/)